# Is it compensation

Tags: nouns

For example, someone’s house is in a plan to make new highway. Then he/she will have to move another land when construction starts. In this case he/she take money from the government to buy a new house and move.

What do you say this monetary help?.
Is it compensation?
Or is there another word especially for use as regale term?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this source **[compensation](http://www.investopedia.com/terms/e/expropriation.asp)** is the appropriate term.

Definition of 'Expropriation'

The act of taking of privately owned property by a government to be used for the benefit of the public. In the United States, the government has the right to take property through eminent domain. The Fifth Amendment to the Constitution provides that private property will not **"be taken for public use without just compensation."** While there is compensation, the expropriation occurs without the property owner's consent.

Investopedia explains 'Expropriation'

Many, but not all, countries support the belief that the expropriating country should pay adequate, **timely and effective compensation** to the involved party. Properties taken through eminent domain are often used for public utilities, highways and railroads. Countries can also expropriate foreign businesses located within the country. Former socialist Chilean President Salvador Allende, for example, expropriated U.S. businesses located in Chile in the early 1970s.

Answer (score 2):

There are various terms of art for the act of the government taking the property for public use: Eminent domain (United States, the Philippines), compulsory purchase (United Kingdom, New Zealand, Ireland), resumption (Hong Kong), resumption/compulsory acquisition (Australia), or expropriation (South Africa, Canada)[1].

I am not aware of any special term for the money specifically. Typically it would be "eminent domain compensation", substituting the term that pertains in the particular jurisdiction for "eminent domain".

[1] http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eminent_domain